# Post variables not being received after form submission

Tags: php, html, mysql, forms, post

So I have a HTML file with the following form:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title></title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <form action="pringles.php" method="post">
      First name:<br>
      <input type="text" name="firstname" value="Mickey">
      <br>
      Last name:<br>
      <input type="text" name="lastname" value="Mouse">
      <br><br>
      <input type="submit" value="Submit">
      </form>
  </body>
</html>
```

Then I have a PHP file names pringles.php which contains the following code:

```
<?php 
// server, username, password, db, port
$servername = "********";
$username = "*******";
$password = "********";
$dbname = "*********";
// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);

foreach ($_POST as $key => $value) {
  $postdata2 = $postdata2 . "Field ".htmlspecialchars($key)." is ".htmlspecialchars($value) . "////";
}

$sql = "INSERT INTO `test`(`text`) VALUES ('{$postdata2}')";
if ($conn->query($sql) === TRUE) {
  echo "New record created successfully";
} else {
    echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . $conn->error;
}
?>
```

However, when I submit the form it inserts a row into my database but the text field is empty. The post variables are not being sent for some reason. Additionally, I have another .php file where a form works perfectly. They are in the same folder and everything, therefore I don't understand why this isn't working.

Thanks!

Comment: `var_dump($postdata2)` shows __what__?

Comment: Why would you enter all POST's into the one column? Or are you wanting to create a new column for each of them? What is the db schema/column type?

Comment: In addition to what @u_mulder mentioned, use what they suggested and then dump `$sql` in there to see what you do get back. Your question is unclear to a certain point.

Comment: @u_mulder its shows NULL

Comment: And `var_dump($_POST)`?

Comment: @FunkFortyNiner The POSTs are entered into one column for testing because the post variables don't seem to be getting sent. It's not an issue of the database, rather the post variables aren't being sent from the form to the php file.

Comment: @u_mulder It says array(0) { }

Comment: @FunkFortyNiner var_dump($sql) returns: string(38) "INSERT INTO `test`(`text`) VALUES ('')"

Comment: I'd start by removing `htmlspecialchars()`. That might be doing more harm than good. If you're using that in hoping to prevent an SQL injection, it isn't the right function for that. Check your column's length also if and when that what I suggest you do works. Also remove `////`.

Comment: @FunkFortyNiner I removed `////` and `htmlspecialchars()`. Still the same thing. The length of the column is set to TEXT and so length to 65535.

Comment: Ok. Well try removing the `foreach` for now and assign a variable to each of the POST arrays and see what that gives. If that works, then it's the loop causing issues somewhere.

Comment: @FunkFortyNiner Still nothing. The post variables are just not being sent for some reason.

Comment: You sure `action="pringles.php"` is correct? What happens if you add an conditional statement to check if any are not empty? If the button is set? It's hard to test this. I don't know what else I can do or say, sorry.

Comment: @FunkFortyNiner I tried it on a different server and it seems to work there. The issue seems to be with the server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue ended up being in the .htaccess as the URL was being redirected to remove the .php and this was causing issues with POST data being lost. This was the code:

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /([^.]+)\.php [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /%1 [NC,L,R]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteRule ^ %{REQUEST_URI}.php [NC,L]
```

This is `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_METHOD} !POST` fixed the problem.